# How to use promises with a unknown amount of tokens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The following code retrieves comments from a comment section of a youtube video. The thing is it retrieves 20 comments and if there is more it retrieves a next token. I am not very experienced using promises so I wonder how can I get all comments in the section until there is no  token anymore?

This code is the example code from a npm package called [youtube-comment-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-comment-api)

I guess my question is very easy to solve, but right now I have no clue.

---

**Example:**

```
const fetchCommentPage = require('youtube-comment-api')
const videoId = 'DLzxrzFCyOs'



fetchCommentPage(videoId)
  .then(commentPage => {
    console.log(commentPage.comments)

    return fetchCommentPage(videoId, commentPage.nextPageToken)
  })
  .then(commentPage => {
    console.log(commentPage.comments)
  })
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work.  What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use recursion in order to get comments from all pages. Something like this should work:

```
// returns a list with all comments
function fetchAllComments(videoId, nextPageToken) {
  // nextPageToken can be undefined for the first iteration
  return fetchCommentPage(videoId, nextPageToken)
   .then(commentPage => {
    if (!commentPage.nextPageToken) {
        return commentPage.comments;
    }
    return fetchAllComments(videoId, commentPage.nextPageToken).then(comments => {
      return commentPage.comments.concat(comments);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Right idea, but there is a small mistake in your method—besides the lack of a return statement, which I corrected. You don't have access to `commentPage.comments` in the last `then`. Perhaps you meant to write `return fetchAllComments(...).then(comments => commentPage.comments.concat(comments))`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that now.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Worked great, but I think its hard to read, so it does not make me liking promises, but I think that is my personal problem :)